# trying to get a 3rd div to "float over" 2 divs which are "float left" and "float right"

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one floating left(#div1) and the other floating right(#div2). I need to add a third div(#div3) which floats centrally over these. I am currently trying to use the z-index. However I am getting some strange effects like the div1 and div2 being forces down. Also the "container" div centrally aligns all child divs.

So for some code:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 980px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; height:130px">
  <div id="div1" style="float:left">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2" style="float:right">Div1</div>
  <div id="div3" style="border:1px solid black;colour:black;position:relative; top:0px, left:auto; z-index:1000">I look like a button and I float the other divs, in a central location</div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate some guidance on the correct code for the above, to ensure that #div3 does float over #div1 and #div2, and is centrally located.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close you `style` attribute in the `div3`. `"` missing at the end

Comment: Add `position: relative` to your `#container` div, and set `position: absolute;` for your `div3`

Comment: Fyi, you're missing a closing quote on your style attribute on div3, which is guaranteed to jack up your styling.

Comment: Thanks. typo on the missing quote, but issue with CSS is the meain cause of my question.... I fear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the style attribute on 3rd div isn't closed.
Use ; to separate between style statements in the style attribute. And its color, not colour
I would also suggest using a css

Heres a codepen:
http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/QwWPYd

If you want the container to float in the center, its enough to give it `margin: auto`
Giving the 3rd div a width and auto margin will get your desired result I would assume. I also removed some unnecessary statements like position relative

```
#div3 {
  border:1px solid black;
  color:black;  
  margin: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Heres a codepen:
http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/gbOyEb

Also consider using `display: flex` and ditch the floats altogether
http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/ogNOVV

If you want to read more on flexbox I recommend the csstricks article http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You really should separate your CSS and HTML, but this is what I did...

Add `width:inherit` to your div3 and `position:absolute`:

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:lightgrey;width: 480px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; height:130px">
  <div id="div1" style="float:left">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2" style="float:right">Div1</div>
  <div id="div3" style="border:1px solid black;colour:black; top:0px, left:auto; z-index:1000; position:absolute; width:inherit;">I look like a button and I float the other divs, in a central location</div>
</div>
```

You can modify the width to adjust where you want `div3` to land and therefore can center it between them if you want.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/re2hkbgh/1/

If this isn't exactly what you want just play with the width to get the effect you want as this is the positioning you are asking for! :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Just trying to get the #div3 with your code to center between #div1 and #div2, with z=index being respected. Just struggling at the moment, seems to left align if I alter the #div3 width attribute, and if I alter the #container width attribute all the divs contract, so I cannot get #div3 between #div1 and #div2/ Perhaps I am missing something fundemental. An example would be useful. Thanks again.

Comment: @SamJolly something like: http://jsfiddle.net/re2hkbgh/2/  (Remove your top and left styling)

Comment: Thanks for this. Altering the #div3 still left aligns the #div3. In the end I went with @vall3y. Thank anyway.

Comment: @SamJolly No problem, glad your question was resolved!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add to `#div3` display property: `inline-block`, and set `text-align: center` to `#container`, check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xcazy7o8/)

Answer (score 1):

No relative or absolutely positioned elements needed! This should give you what you want:

CSS:

```
#container{width: 580px; border:2px solid orange; height:350px;}
#div1{border:2px solid blue; width:260px; height:100px; float:left;}
#div2{border:2px solid green; width:260px; float:right; height:100px;}
#div3{border:1px solid black; width:100%; float:left; height:100px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" >
    <div id="div3">I look like a button and I float the other divs, in a central location</div>
  <div id="div1">Div1</div>
  <div id="div2">Div3</div>
</div>
```

Heres a live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lza5fz43/

Comment: Well I misunderstood: " I need to add a third div(#div3) which floats centrally over these."

Comment: Apparently my comment got deleted.  Right it is misleading. but he does say what he doesn't want ;)